# How can I save settings to project settings tab?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the project properties in settings tab, I added the value `*.*`.
Then I added another Setting1 and added to its value `c:\`

Then in form1 constructor:

```
textBox2.Text = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["Setting"];
textBox3.Text = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["Setting1"];
```

I want that each time the user type something in one of the textboxes, it will save it to settings.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default["Setting"] = textBox2.Text;
}

private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default["Setting1"] = textBox3.Text;
}
```

But each time I'm running my program I'm getting the first settings `*.*` and `c:\`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are not saving the changes that you are doing to your `Properties.Settings` properties. To save the changes you must do this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```